# IndexedDB data file duplicity when updating records

Tags: indexeddb

I have a problem with duplicities in **IndexedDB** data file in Chrome.

> "AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Userdata/Default/IndexedDB/site/000003.log".

I can see the record just once in the database but if I search for the record in data file, I find it as many times as I update the record. What I am doing wrong?

Here is sample code:

```
var firstLoad = false,
    db = null;

openDb = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let req = window.indexedDB.open("testDB", 1);

    req.onsuccess = (e) => {
      db = e.target.result;
      resolve();
    };

    req.onupgradeneeded = (e) => {
      firstLoad = true;
      db = e.target.result;
      db.createObjectStore("testStore", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    };
  });
};

insertRecord = (record) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let tx = db.transaction(["testStore"], "readwrite"),
        store = tx.objectStore("testStore");

    tx.oncomplete = () => {
      resolve();
    };
    store.add(record);
  });
};

updateRecord = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let tx = db.transaction(["testStore"], "readwrite"),
        store = tx.objectStore("testStore"),
        req = store.get(1);

    tx.oncomplete = () => {
      resolve();
    };

    req.onsuccess = (e) => {
      store.put(e.target.result);
    }
  });
};

testIt = async () => {
  await openDb();
  if (firstLoad)
    await insertRecord({id:1,name:"record"});
  updateRecord();
};

testIt();
```

Comment: What you are doing wrong is inspecting a file you probably should not be inspecting.

Comment: Josh, do you realize that with this issue the database will unnecessary grow in size with every update you make?